# AutoCompletionTextView row height resizing

Tags: android, resize, drop-down-menu, row

Hi Android developers,

I want to display 8 to 10 records in my AutoCompletionTextView. But by default it shows only four records. If I can reduce the "Row height" it is possible to view more rows. Can any one tell me how to re-size the drop down row?

Thanks in Advance,
Jeyan.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

here by default it is showing about 7 records, and also the auto-complete will be showing the matching characters, may be the alphabets that you have entered will be matched only for that words. I believe this is what you are looking for.